# Densifying many shapes at same time using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have all these shapes to densify

[image]

I thought it will be better if I code with ArcPy in order to densify all the shapes once at a time.

So I thought of this code:

```
#creat the list of shapes to densify
liste_ligne =["E1_H20A_H35_D21E", "E1_I_H16A_H18B","E1_K_D16A_D18B","E1_L_H14_H16B","E1_H2_D70_D40C","G1_D50_D55_H40C","E1_H1_D60_D65_H70","E1_M_D12_H12","E1_Bbis_H45","E1_C_H18A","E1_C_H40","E1_D20A_D21A_D35","E1_E_D18A","E1_E_H50","E1_Bbis_D20E1","E1_G2_D21C_H60_H65","E1_LM_LoisirMoyen","E1_Bbis_D20E","E1_F2_D40_D45","E1_LL_LoisirLong","E1_ABIS_H20E_H21A","E1_F1_H55_H21C","E1_Lbis_D16B_D14"]
for ligne in liste_ligne:
    arcpy.Densify_edit(ligne, "DISTANCE", "4 Meters")
```

The code showed me an error so there's something wrong that I can't figure out.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What's your question? It's unclear what, if anything, you're having trouble with.

Comment: Have you established your arcpy.env.workspace, and are all of these items located in that workspace?